# Error when setting values from JSON on my UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, json, xcode, xcode5

I have a problem when set values on my `UITableViewCell`. 
I get this data from Web Service in JSON format, to do this created a class that contains all the data from JSON.

That is the Class.

Refunds.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Refunds : NSObject

 -(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;

 @property (assign) NSNumber *refunds_id;
 @property (assign) NSNumber *request_number;
 @property (strong) NSString *policy_code;
 @property (strong) NSString *company;

 @end
```

Refunds.m

```
#import "Refunds.h"

 @implementation Refunds 

 @synthesize refunds_id;
 @synthesize request_number;
 @synthesize policy_code;
 @synthesize company;
 -(id)initWithJSONData:(NSArray*)data{
 self = [super init];
 if(self){
    NSLog(@"initWithJSONData method called ");

    //NSString *u = [data valueForKey:@"policy_code"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",u);

    refunds_id =  [data valueForKey:@"id"];
    request_number = [data valueForKey:@"request_number"];
    policy_code = [data valueForKey:@"policy_code"];
    company = [data valueForKey:@"company"];
    }
    return self;
    }
    @end
```

In the ViewController where I use the `UITableVIew` I have this implementation

```
NSMutableArray refunds_view = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *each_refunds in self.list) {
    Refunds *refunds = [[Refunds alloc] initWithJSONData:each_refunds];
    [refunds_view addObject:refunds];
}
```

In the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

I have this:

```
Refunds *current = [refunds_view objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.date_admission.text = [current company];
```

In the line **cell.date_admission.text = [current company];** gives me the following error

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bc4eb0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bc4eb0'
```

That is the JSON Format.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "holder_rut": 12345678,
    "holder_name": "Otro Pedro",
    "rut": 12345678,
    "name": "Otro Pedro",
    "refunds_view": [
        {
            "id": 60,
            "request_number": 456789,
            "policy_code": "3500009001",
            "company": "Benefits",
            "beneficiary_id": 1,
            "concept": "Prueba More",
            "date": "2014-05-21",
            "amount": 20000,
            "deductible_amount": 0,
            "max_applied": 0,
            "yearly_balance": 97,
            "payment_amount": 14000,
            "payment_method": "Deposito",
            "bank": "Estado",
            "account_number": "1234567",
            "payment_date": "2014-06-20",
            "created_at": "2014-06-18 21:55:41"
        }
    ]
}
```

The data I need to show is that this **refunds_view**

**View Controller Code**

```
//UITableView Methods Implemented
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleCell";

RowCell *cell = (RowCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    //inicilitacion cell custom
    cell = [[RowCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


Refunds *current = [refunds_view objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"company %@",[current company]);
cell.date_admission.text = [current company];


return cell;
}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

//Geting data from JSON Refunds
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary
                      dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rut_user, nil]
                      forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rut", nil]];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonWriter dataWithObject:dict];

//URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
//[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];//TOKEN
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];//I'm a Json Refunds


self.list = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"refunds_view"];
NSLog(@"Quantity of Refunds Founds %i",[self.list count]);

refunds_view = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (NSDictionary *each_refunds in self.list) {
    //NSLog(@"each_refound %@",each_refunds);
    Refunds *refunds = [[Refunds alloc] initWithJSONData:each_refunds];
    [refunds_view addObject:refunds];
}   
}
```

I need Fix it ASAP.
Thanks. 
Best Regards.

Hi everyone. 
I try this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[current company]);

2014-06-26 10:32:13.917 Benefits[7178:70b] (
Benefits
)

cell.sol_number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", current.company];
```

no occurs the error But the value doesn't show complete, only show **(**

Any idea for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try putting log while initializing entity. Over there check whether proper value is getting assigned to "company" or not. I guess there is the problem

Comment: Why does `initWithJSONData` accept an `NSArray`?

Comment: Why do you use assign for `NSNumber` properties?

Comment: Thanks @Mrunal This is the **NSLog(@"company %@",[current company]);** `2014-06-26 02:55:08.466 Benefits[6389:70b] company (
    Benefits
)`

Comment: Try `cell.date_admission.text = [[current company] objectAtIndex:0];` and check if it works or not.

Comment: Doesn't work @Akhilrajtr...

Comment: Also please check if your JSON-response has a stable format and "company" value always is a `NSString` value

Comment: Ok ok. Yes always the format company is NSString

Comment: Are you call `[self.list length]`? In my opinion it's not enough info to localize the issue. Could you please post more code of the view controller?

Comment: First of all NSNumber shouldn't have `assign` attribute. Depends how you want but try to change to `strong` attribute. `Assign` are usually used in primitive data types

Comment: Thanks @sumofighter666 but doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the new code, but still no new ideas. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks safe, not sure about about the other methods of view controller

Comment: Ok ok @AlexPeda I put a new code to get data from JSON.

Comment: Try to do : cell.date_admission.text = @"<Dummy Text>"; and check whether dummy text is getting displayed in cell or not. Because if entity class is fine then the other cause can be the cell.

Comment: Hi @Mrunal I try cell.date_admission.text = @"Testing"  and working. I can see testing in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Rewrite your Refund.m like below

    #import "Refunds.h"

     @implementation Refunds 

     @synthesize refunds_id;
     @synthesize request_number;
     @synthesize policy_code;
     @synthesize company;

-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data
{
     self = [super init];
     if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"initWithJSONData method called ");

        refunds_id =  data[@"id"];
        request_number = data[@"request_number"];
        policy_code = data[@"policy_code"];
        company = data[@"company"];
    }
        return self;
}
    @end
```

Comment: Put a break point on initWithJsonData method, and check all properties are getting value or not.

Comment: I try this and this is the error when Rewrite **Refund.m**      `-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8abbbe0
2014-06-26 03:05:21.604 Benefits[6467:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8abbbe0'`

Comment: pls send NSLog of each_refunds dictionary

Comment: this is the **NSLog(@"%@",each_refunds)** `2014-06-26 03:11:43.496 Benefits[6520:70b] each_refound (
        {
        "account_number" = 1234567;
        amount = 20000;
        bank = Estado;
        "beneficiary_id" = 1;
        company = Benefits;
        concept = "Prueba More";
        "created_at" = "2014-06-18 21:55:41";
        date = "2014-05-21";
        "deductible_amount" = 0;
        id = 60;
        "max_applied" = 0;
        "payment_amount" = 14000;
    }
)
`

Comment: ok I did this but leaving the class as had and each is filled with the value corresponding to the JSON

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your method definition in .mm file, instead of NSDictionary you have used NSArray in method parameters. Other than that your code and logic is fine.

Refunds.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Refunds : NSObject

 -(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;
```

Whereas in Refunds.mm file

```
#import "Refunds.h"

 @implementation Refunds 

 -(id)initWithJSONData:(NSArray*)data{ ... }
```

I would suggest, always try to do copy-paste to avoid such human errors.

Answer (score 0):

cell.date_admission.text = [[current objectAtIndex:0] company];